# Probability of a single number from a set $\{1,2,3...1000\}$ being a multiple of any two $7,11$ or $13$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

I am asked to pick a single number uniformly at random from the set $\{1,2,3...1000\}$. What is the probability that it's a multiple of any two of the numbers $7,11$ or $13$.

It would be very helpful for me to visualize the solution by observing how one should approach this type of problem

Comment: It might be useful for you to try a smaller problem first: Pick a single number uniformly from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 104\}$.  What is the probability that this number is a multiple of any two of the numbers $3$, $5$, or $7$?  List out all the multiples of $3 \times 5 = 15$, $3 \times 7 = 21$, and $5 \times 7 = 35$.  Do you see a pattern in how often they occur?  (It may be easier to see if you initially include $105$ in the set.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a number is a multiple of any two of the numbers $7$, $11$, or $13$, then it divides either $7*11 = 77$ (there are $\lfloor \frac{1000}{77} \rfloor = 12$ of them), or $11*13 = 143$ (there are $\lfloor \frac{1000}{143} \rfloor = 6$ of them) or $7*13 = 91$ (there are $\lfloor \frac{1000}{91} \rfloor = 10$ of them). One can also note that those three classes of numbers do not intersect, as $7*11*13 = 1001 > 1000$. So the total number of such numbers is $28$. And as our numbers are uniformly distributed, our probability is $\frac{28}{1000}$.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you for your solution. This makes sense

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** : You can prove that that the number of integers below $n$ divisible by $k$ is equal to $\lfloor \frac n k\rfloor $. Then by using inclusion–exclusion principle you should be able to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

To be a multiple of any two numbers, it must be a multiple of the least common muliplte (LCM) of those two numbers. In this case, all three numbers are prime so the LCM of any two is simply the product of the two. Here we have $$7*11=77,\text{ }7*13=91, \text{ and }11*13=143$$

If you divide each $product%$ into $1000$, you will find the number of multiples of that product. 
Now, since $$\text{INT}(1000/77)=12,\text{ INT}(1000/91)=10,\text{ and INT}(1000/143)=6,$$

we have $12+10+6=28$ chances out of a thousand of drawing a multiple of any two of $7,11,\text{ or }13$. Subtract three if you do not count 1 $times$ as a multiple.

Comment: This intuitively makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @Adam You can show appreciation for useful answers by upvoting them or marking them $\color{green}\checkmark$